# Is it possible to implement sequence programming with vararg in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, sequence

I've been trying sequence programming for processing the data I get from the vararg argument. I want to multiply every number in the list and add it to the new array list. Is it possible to use sequences.

I attach the code below:

```
fun main() {
    val number = asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
    print(number)
}

fun <T> asList(vararg input: T): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    input.map {it * 2}.foreach(result.add(it))
    return result
}
```

Here is the error I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4T8u.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a sequence from a vararg; I'll come back to that later.

First, the main problem in the code above is that, unfortunately, it can't be done generically.  The error you're getting is because `T` could be any type, and most types can't be multiplied, so the compiler is telling you that you can't do the `* 2`.

You might think of restricting `T` to subclasses of [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/), but that doesn't help.  (`Number` is a very weak type; it doesn't let you do any arithmetic, probably because you can't tell what type the result would have to be, nor what rounding or overflow might occur.  All it lets you do is convert the value to specific types.)

But if you remove the type parameter and code it for a particular numeric type, such as `Int`, then it can work fine.

There are also spelling and syntax errors in the code around the `foreach` call.  Fixing those too gives e.g.:

```
fun asList(vararg input: Int): List<Int> {
    val result = ArrayList<Int>()
    input.map{ it * 2 }.forEach{ result.add(it) }
    return result
}
```

That's doing a lot of unnecessary work, though; the `map()` already returns a list, so there's no point in creating a second list and copying to it element-by-element!  Also, the name is misleading.  So it could just be:

```
fun asListDoubled(vararg input: Int) = input.map{ it * 2 }
```

Your question mentioned sequences; but your code uses normal eager lists.  If you want a lazily-evaluated sequence, you can just add an [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) call, e.g.:

```
fun asSequenceDoubled(vararg input: Int) = input.asSequence().map{ it * 2 }
```

But note that this now returns a `Sequence<Int>`, not `List<Int>`, so you can go on and do further lazy operations on it.  (If you want a `List<Int>`, then you can just append a `toList()` call — but there's little point in using a sequence only for the doubling, as the sequence overhead is probably far higher than any saving.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the problem is solved. I really appreciate your explanation. Out of my previous question, I'm wondering whether it is possible to use Generic Data Type and checking whether the value is a number or not before processing the data as I do below:

fun <T> asListNumber(vararg input: T): List<T> = input.filter{ isNumber(it) }.map {it * 2}

Comment: @auliaamirullah No, because as I said, `Number` doesn't let you do any arithmetic: there's no `plus()` method, so you can't use `* 2` on a `Number`, only on the individual numeric types `Int`, `Long`, `Short`, `Char`, `Byte`, `Float`, and `Double`.